# How to properly apply this nested ifstream?

Tags: c++11, nested, ifstream

I want to use an `ifstream`  function that calls another `ifstream` function inside it, but I have no idea why it does not work. The ifstream called first works fine, but the second one does not. This is the first one:

```
ifstream archivo("civilizaciones.txt");
if(archivo.is_open()){
    while(!archivo.eof()){
        string name;
        Civilizacion a;

        getline(archivo, name);

        if(archivo.eof()){ break; }
        a.setName(name);
        arreglo.push_back(a);
        c.recuperarAld(name);
    }
}
```

`c.recuperarAld(name)` Calls the following function in a class with object c:

```
void Civilizacion::recuperarAld(string name)
{
    ifstream aldeanoss(name + ".txt");
    if(aldeanoss.is_open()){
        while(!aldeanoss.eof()){
            Aldeano a;
            string linea;

            getline(aldeanoss,linea);

            if(aldeanoss.eof()){break;}

            a.setNombre(linea);

            getline(aldeanoss, linea);
            a.setEdad(stoul(linea));

            getline(aldeanoss, linea);
            a.setGenero(linea);

            getline(aldeanoss, linea);
            a.setSalud(stoi(linea));

            aldeanos.push_back(a);
        }
    }
}
```

But this second one does not seem to work, how can I fix it?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead? Also, a variable named `c` is not declared anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: What do you mean with "Doesn't work"? `aldeanoss.is_open()` returns false?

Comment: What I meant it to do is that, civilizaciones.txt would create a file in which each line be the name of the .txt's created by `recuperarAld` (the reason for `c.recuperarAld(name)` and `ifstream aldeanoss(name + ".txt")` , but it does not create any file from the function `recuperarAld(...)`. The object for the class Civilizacion is `c`.